# Target URL scheme XXX is not allowed

Tags: adaptive-cards

I have an Adaptive Card entirely made in html which is sent by email using a windows console app.  I receive the card very well, everything is find in it and the URL for the Action.Http is well formed and working as it is tested outside the card now when I click Send from the Adaptive Card in outlook DESKTOP or WEB it shows a message saying :

The URL scheme XXXX is not allowed.

the URL is very normal which is an MVC action I'm calling that looks like that :

http://localhost:52523/Controller/Action?With_a_phew_parameters

When I paste the url in the browser it works just find.

Any idea ?

Comment: If I take the URL directly from the card in outlook by looking at the source and use it directly in the browser it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did set my MVC app to use https and changed the URL for https:// and the error was resolved

Answer (score 2):

URL must be accessible from the internet, you cannot use localhost.
read at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/adaptive-card